# Iterating over columns in a data frame in order to replace values from matching data in list of data frames

Tags: r, dataframe, replace, apply, sapply

I'm interested in building a function making use of `apply`/`sapply` or `Map` that would iterate over available columns in **`dta`** and replace values in each column with matched values from data frame available in a nameless list of data frames with list item index corresponding to the column number of the **`dta`** data frame.

## Example

Given objects:

```
set.seed(1)
size <- 20

# Data set
dta <-
    data.frame(
        unitA = sample(LETTERS[1:4], size = size, replace = TRUE),
        unitB = sample(letters[16:20], size = size, replace = TRUE),
        unitC = sample(month.abb[1:4], size = size, replace = TRUE),
        someValue = sample(1:1e6, size = size, replace = TRUE)
    )

# Meta data
lstMeta <- list(
    # Unit A definitions
    data.frame(
        V1 = c("A", "B", "D"),
        V2 = c("Letter A", "Letter B", "Letter D")
    ),
    # Unit B definitions
    data.frame(
        V1 = c("t", "q"),
        V2 = c("small t", "small q")
    ),
    # Unit C definitions
    data.frame(
        V1 = c("Mar", "Jan"),
        V2 = c("March", "January")
    )
)
```

### Desired results

When applied on **`dta`**, the  function should return a `data.frame` corresponding to the extract below:

```
unitA       unitB    unitC      someValue
Letter B    small t  Apr        912876
Letter B    small q  March      293604
       C    s        Apr        459066
Letter D    p        March      332395
Letter A    small q  March      650871
Letter D    small q  Apr        258017
Letter D    p        January    478546
C           small q  Feb        766311
C           small t  March      84247
Letter A    small q  March      875322
Letter A    r        Feb        339073
Letter A    r        Ap         839441
C           r        Feb        346684
Letter B    p        January    333775
Letter D    small t  January    476352
(...)
```

## Existing approach

```
replaceLbls <- function(dataSet, lstDict) {
    sapply(seq_along(dataSet), function(i) {
        # Take corresponding metadata data frame
        dtaDict <- lstDict[[i]]

        # Replace values in selected column
        # Where matches on V1 push corrsponding values from V2
        dataSet[,i][match(dataSet[,i], dtaDict[,1])] <- dtaDict[,2][match(dtaDict[,1], dataSet[,i])]  
    })
}

# Testing -----------------------------------------------------------------

replaceLbls(dataSet = dta, lstDict = lstMeta)
```

*Of course the approach proposed above does not work as it will try to use `NA` in assignments; but it summarises what I want to achieve:*

> Error in `x[...] <- m` : `NAs` are not allowed in subscripted assignments
>   In addition: Warning message: In `[<-.factor(*tmp*, match(dataSet[,
>   i], dtaDict[, 1]), value = c(NA,`  :   invalid factor level, NA
>   generated

## Additional remarks

### Source data set

The key characteristics of the data are:

- The list is nameless so subsetting has to be done by item numbers not by names
- Item number correspond to column numbers
- There is no full match between metadata data frames available in the list of data frames and *unit* columns available in the data
- The `someValue` column also should be iterated over as it *may* contain labels that should be replaced

### Solution

- I'm not interested in [`dplyr`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/index.html)/[`data.table`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html)/[`sqldf`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sqldf/index.html)-based solutions.
- I'm not interested in nested `for`-loops

Comment: Does first column correspond to first list element 2nd col with 2nd list element and so on? i.e. Would something like `mapply(function(x, y) x$V2[match(y, x$V1)], lstMeta, dta[1:3])` be acceptable? (at its final form)

Comment: @Sotos Yes, and `Map`/`apply` family sounds like a way to go. Ideally, I would iterate over the whole `dta` as I won't know the size of `dta` but I can assume that number of elements in the list reflects number of columns in `dta`.

Comment: Ok let me work on it a bit and I ll post an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following approach works well for the example data:

```
replaceLbls <- function(dataSet, lstDict) {
  dataSet[seq_along(lstDict)] <- Map(function(x, lst) {
    x <- as.character(x)
    idx <- match(x, as.character(lst$V1))
    replace(x, !is.na(idx), as.character(lst$V2)[na.omit(idx)])
  }, dataSet[seq_along(lstDict)], lstDict)
  dataSet
}


head(replaceLbls(dta, lstMeta))
#      unitA   unitB unitC someValue
# 1 Letter B small t   Apr    912876
# 2 Letter B small q March    293604
# 3        C       s   Apr    459066
# 4 Letter D       p March    332395
# 5 Letter A small q March    650871
# 6 Letter D small q   Apr    258017
```

This assumes that you want to apply the changes to the first X column of the data that are as long as the meta-list. You might want to include an extra step to convert back to factor since this approach converts the adjusted columns to character class.

Another remark on factors: you could potentially speed up the performance by working only on the levels of any factor variables instead the whole column. The general process would be similar but requires a few more steps to check classes etc.

Answer (score 2):

I have a hacky solution that doesn't use `for` loops or other packages. I needed to convert the `factors` to `characters` for it to work but you might be able to improve my solution.

The solution works by only matching values that are found in your `lstMeta` by creating a vector of indices where matches are found. I also used the `<<-` operator. If you're better at `R` than me, you can probably improve this.

```
set.seed(1)
size <- 20

# Data set
dta <-
  data.frame(
    unitA = sample(LETTERS[1:4], size = size, replace = TRUE),
    unitB = sample(letters[16:20], size = size, replace = TRUE),
    unitC = sample(month.abb[1:4], size = size, replace = TRUE),
    someValue = sample(1:1e6, size = size, replace = TRUE),
    stringsAsFactors = F
  )

# Meta data
lstMeta <- list(
  # Unit A definitions
  data.frame(
    V1 = c("A", "B", "D"),
    V2 = c("Letter A", "Letter B", "Letter D"),
    stringsAsFactors = F
  ),
  # Unit B definitions
  data.frame(
    V1 = c("t", "q"),
    V2 = c("small t", "small q"),
    stringsAsFactors = F
  ),
  # Unit C definitions
  data.frame(
    V1 = c("Mar", "Jan"),
    V2 = c("March", "January"),
    stringsAsFactors = F
  )
)

replaceLbls <- function(dataSet, lstDict) {
  sapply(1:3, function(i) {
    # Take corresponding metadata data frame
    dtaDict <- lstDict[[i]]

    # Replace values in selected column
    # Where matches on V1 push corrsponding values from V2
    myUniques <- which(dataSet[,i] %in% dtaDict[,1])

    dataSet[myUniques,i]<<- dtaDict[,2][match(dataSet[myUniques,i],dtaDict[,1])]  
  })
  return(dataSet)
}

# Testing -----------------------------------------------------------------

replaceLbls(dataSet = dta, lstDict = lstMeta)
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, +1 but I will wait with accepting if there is nothing else. I'm slightly apprehensive about using **`<<-`** this function is called from within a module in a Shiny app so there is some risk here in pushing things to parent env. It's a lot things there, I would rather avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this:

```
mapr<-function(t,meta){
    ind<-match(t,meta$V1)
    if(!is.na(ind)){return(meta$V2[ind])}
    else{return(t)}}
```

Then using `sapply`:

```
dta<-as.data.frame(cbind(sapply(1:3,function(t,df,meta){sapply(df[,t],mapr,lstMeta[[t]])},dta,lstMeta,simplify = T),dta[,4]))
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of `mapply`s can do the job

```
f1 <- function(df, lst){
  d1 <- setNames(data.frame(mapply(function(x, y) x$V2[match(y, x$V1)], lst, df[1:3]), 
                            df$someValue, stringsAsFactors = FALSE), 
                 names(df))
  as.data.frame(mapply(function(x, y) replace(x, is.na(x), y[is.na(x)]), d1, df))

}
```